# How can we access large payload response from lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function written in nodejs which returns response more than payload limit. So I am trying to handle it through s3 pre-signed url. I have created pre-singed url where I have a json file and I am able to write response successfully, but when trying to access directly from browser, it gives me SignatureDoesNotMatch error. Also I am not able to access that response. I need that response in my react application. Can someone help me on that. Below is my code as of now:

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";
import aws from 'aws-sdk';

export const handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    const neptuneEndpoint = "https://mynarz-neptune-cluster.cluster-cr6kmspyprba.us-east-1.neptune.amazonaws.com:25881/sparql";
    const Query = event.body;
    const s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01',signatureVersion: 'v4' });
    console.log('query=> ',clinicalStudiesQuery);
    const request_params = (query) =>  ({
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/sparql-results",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      },
      method: "POST",
      body: `${query}`
    });

    //1. get response
    const fetchClinicalStudies = await fetch( neptuneEndpoint, 
    request_params(clinicalStudiesQuery));
    const response = await fetchClinicalStudies.json();
    const responseJson = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": response,
        "isBase64Encoded": false
    };
    console.log("response from neptune=>",responseJson);

    //2. save response in s3 presigned url
    const filename = 'data/data.json';
    const s3params = {
    Bucket: 'mybucket-web-host-dev-s3',
    Key: filename,
    ContentType: 'application/json',
  };

  try {
    const presignedUrl = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', s3params);
    console.log('The presigned URL is:', presignedUrl);
    console.log(presignedUrl)
    
    const s3response = await fetch(presignedUrl, {
        method: "PUT",
        body: JSON.stringify(responseJson),
        key: filename,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    });
    
    var getparams = {
      Bucket: "mybucket-web-host-dev-s3", 
      Key: filename
     };
     
    console.log("s3response=>",s3response);
    //return presignedUrl;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error while generating presigned URL:', error.message);
    throw new Error(error);
  }
    
  //3. return response for react application
  return responseJson;
};
```

Comment: In this post method I am sending sparql query as a request to aws neptune endpoint and getting query result as a response.

Comment: Also do I need to add secretAccessKey, and accessKeyId somewhere, is it mandatory?